# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'p' in

Tags: preg-replace

When i type in my search form and i click search with this keyword make / people is read the first (make) but not the second (people)

This is my code

```
for($k=$no_words; $k>0 ;$k--)
        {
            $w=trim($search_array[$k-1]);
            if($w!='')
            {
                $result[$i]['description'] = preg_replace('~'.$search_array[$k-1].'~i','<b>'.$search_array[$k-1].'</b>',$result[$i]['description']);
                $result[$i]['title'] = preg_replace('~'.$search_array[$k-1].'~','<b>'.$search_array[$k-1].'</b>',$result[$i]['title']);
            }
        }
```

Comment: although this question is terrible, the problem is that you use the delimiter `/` for your Regexp. But `/` also occurs in the string you use as regexp. Choose a different delimiter, for example `!`. Also, your code does not make sense. Why is the regexp in some kind of array?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: Who ok! i put that ! now is work with this make / people but not with this make ! people

Comment: Ok i have update the full code

Comment: When you use a variable inside a pattern, keep in mind that the variable can contain the delimiter character and break your pattern. To prevent this, you need to use the `preg_quote` function to escape regex special character and delimiter you have choosen: `'~' . preg_quote($search_array[$k-1], '~') . '~i'`

Comment: Ok i try it $result[$i]['description'] = preg_quote($search_array[$k-1], '~') . '~i','<b>'.$search_array[$k-1].'</b>',$result[$i]['description']); but is not work again

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: Warning: preg_quote() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Comment: Arrgh, you haven't understood! You don't need to change all, you only need to process your variable with preg_quote: `$result[$i]['description'] = preg_replace('~'.preg_quote($search_array[$k-1], '~').'~i', ...`

Comment: Yes ok i change it but now is not working when i search with this term make ~ people

Comment: Ok! I make it this is preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($search_array[$k-1], '/') . ')/', '<b>\\1</b>', $result[$i]['description']);